# expect set variable in bash context

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, expect

Do you know if it is possible to assign and print expect variable in a expect script encapsulate in a bash script. Ok this is not clear I know, let's see the example below :

```
#!/bin/bash

..some bash code..

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
  set hello "abcd"
  puts "$hello"
  exit
EOF
```

Normally, it should print out "abcd" as this is the content of the variable "hello", but it prints me nothing.. just blank "\n" space

```
lionel@pc:~$ ./call_to_bash_script.sh

lionel@pc:~$
```

Expect is working well as if I try to do just : puts "abcd" it prints me it out.

```
lionel@pc:~$ ./call_to_bash_script.sh
abcd  
lionel@pc:~$
```

Comment: And if you put the `set hello "abcd"` before the `expect` call? `<<EOF` (heredoc) treats everything as a string (an `expect` script in this case), so it won't execute bash commands there.

Comment: If I put before heredoc just like that : /usr/bin/expect set hello "abcd" << EOF... the scripts tries the read set as a file : couldn't read file "set": no such file or directory.

The problem with a script is that it need to be called from a bash script and I need to passed to the expect script a tons of variables. I don't wan't to waste time parsing all that variable in the expect script, that why bash is quite useful. I'm calling a expect proc which return a code (0 or 1) that I need to test if it success or not. And I can't affect a value to a variable.

Comment: I should have been more clear, sorry. The `<<EOF` is of course part of the command. So:  `set hello "abcd";  /usr/bin/expect <<EOF`. So, place the `set hello` with the `.. some bash code..`.

Comment: No problem ;) I try what you suggest but it doesn't work :'(

Comment: @kenny, you're on the wrong track here. `set hello abcd` belongs in the expect code, so inside the heredoc. In bash, `set hello abcd` will set `$1` to "hello" and `$2` to "abcd"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heredocs expand bash variable references. Bash is expanding `$hello` before expect ever gets a chance to see it. You can disable variable expansion by quoting the `EOF` delimiter like so:

```
/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF'
  set hello "abcd"
  puts "$hello"
  exit
EOF
```

Or by escaping the variable reference:

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
  set hello "abcd"
  puts "\$hello"
  exit
EOF
```