# counter loop does not increment inside of expect

Tags: linux, loops, while-loop, debian, expect

I am trying to run this script, where there is a loop inside expect. The problem is the counter is not incremented, so, the loop does not end.
Follow the code:

```
        counter2=1
        expect << END_EXPECT
        set timeout 60;
        spawn ssh user@$1
        while {$counter2 < $file_size } {
                send "\r";
                expect "user@$1>";
                send "${xpath[counter2]}";
                set counter2 [ expr $counter2 + 1];
                send $counter2;
        }
        send 'quit\r'
END_EXPECT
```

The line send $counter2 show me that it is not incremented as expected.
The expectation is that the script logs once, send n times the xpath. But what happens is a infinite loop.
What should be wrong?
PS: I am using Debian, and it is a bash script.

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1):

`set counter2 [ expr $counter2 + 1];` -- Because the expect code is in an unquoted heredoc, the shell will expand *all* variables *before* launching expect. The only thing expect sees is: `set counter2 [ expr 0 + 1]`.

Even if we fix that, you won't be able to index the shell array with an expect variable. You have a shell interpreter running an expect interpreter: those two processes **cannot** share variables like you want.

You have to put the shell variables into the environment where expect can retrieve them (with the Tcl `env` array). Unfortunately, arrays cannot be put into the environment.

Show some more of that program, and I can help you refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

This line `set counter2 [ expr $counter2 + 1];` in your code, cause the variable `counter2` in expect context rather in bash context. Your code are using expect in bash, so you need to use `\$counter2` to quote the variable rather `$counter2`.
My test.sh code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

out_para=1

expect <<EOF
set out_para_cp $out_para
spawn cat /root/sample.txt
expect {
"test" {
send "\$out_para_cp\r";
set out_para_cp [ expr \$out_para_cp + 1 ];
exp_continue
}
EOF
```

and my /root/sample.txt is here:

```
test
test
```

There is the output of test.sh:

```
~ $ sh test.sh
spawn cat /root/sample.txt
test
test
1
2
```

The increase operation success.

I learn it from [expect set variable in bash context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897440/expect-set-variable-in-bash-context).